# How to write a cron for every 30 minutes between 2AM to 4AM?

Tags: linux, cron

I was trying to figure a cron for every 30 minutes between 2AM to 4AM?
So the cron run time will be: 2:00 2:30 3:00 3:30 4:00

Every hour will be something like this:
0 2,3,4 * * *  command

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just write it as two distinct rules:

```
0,30 2-3 * * * /run/this/command
0    4   * * * /run/this/command
```

If you're the sort that worries about this sort of thing (I'm not), you can use a conditional to get it onto one line:

```
0,30 2-4 * * * [[ "$(date +%H%M)" != "0430" ]] && /run/this/command
```

This will run the command given at 4:30 as well, but not actually call your *script* unless the time is something other than 4:30.

Comment: I like this answer, but is it possible to write it in 1 line?